# What is the explanation for this behaviour of scanf?

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I have this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char vc[5]={1,1,1,1,0};
    int vi[4]={0,0,0,0};

    printf("Reading characters...\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
        scanf("%c",&vc[i]);

    printf("Reading numbers...\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
        scanf("%d",&vi[i]);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    printf("%c ",vc[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    printf("%d ",vi[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I can only enter 2 characters before it prints "Reading numbers" and goes to the next for loop. Why does the iteration only last 2 steps? It should be 4.

Comment: You are typing ENTER between entering characters. That generates a newline. You asked `scanf` to read characters and the newline is a character (specifically `'\n'`).

Comment: Well that explains a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `%c` doesn't ignore whitespace and you're probably hitting return. Try:

```
scanf(" %c",&vc[i]);
       ^
```

The space makes `scanf` ignore any whitespace.

Comment: You should put the space at the beginning, not the end. By discarding trailing white space, you're forcing scanf to read up to the next non-white space character, which is almost never the behavior you want.

Comment: Probably better to put the space before the directive, otherwise the `scanf` won't return before it finds the next non-whitespace.